# How to play a sound at random time but with a minimum time interval

Tags: android

I am trying to build a meditation app with Android Studio.
I need that app plays a sound (bell) at random time but with minimum interval time (for example 1 minute).

Thanks

Comment: Hi Maxello, please read the "how to ask" guidelines before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int minIntervalMs = 60000;     //1 minute
int maxintervalMs = 5 * 60000; //5 minutes
int interval = r.nextInt(maxintervalMs - minIntervalMs) + minIntervalMs;
```

This way You get a millisecond interval between 1 an 5 minutes.